# Using stream to treat received data

Tags: c++, stream, istream, istream-iterator

I am receiving messages from a socket.
The socket is packed within a header (that is basically the size of the message) and a footer that is a crc (a kind of code to check if the message is not corrupted)

So, the layout is something like :

```
size (2 bytes) | message (240 bytes) | crc (4 byte)
```

I wrote a `operator>>`

The `operator>>` is as following :

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &stream, Message &msg) {
    std::int16_t size;
    stream >> size;
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&msg), size);

    // Not receive enough data
    if (stream.rdbuf()->in_avail() < dataSize + 4) {
        stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
        return stream;
    }

    std::int16_t gotCrc;
    stream >> gotCrc;

    // Data not received correctly
    if(gotCrc != computeCrc(msg)) {
        stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

The message can arrive byte by byte, or can arrive totally. We can even receive several messages in once.

Basically, what I did is something like this :

```
struct MessageReceiver {
    std::string totalDataReceived;
    void messageArrived(std::string data) {
        // We add the data to totaldataReceived
        totalDataReceived += data;

        std::stringbuf buf(totalDataReceived);
        std::istream stream(&buf);
        std::vector<Message> messages(
            std::istream_iterator<Message>(stream), 
            std::istream_iterator<Message>{});
        std::for_each(begin(messages), end(messages), processMessage);
        // +4 for crc and + 2 for the size to remove
        auto sizeToRemove = [](auto init, auto message) {return init + message.size + 4 + 2;};
        // remove the proceed messages
        totalDataReceived.remove(accumulate(begin(messages), end(messages), 0, sizeToRemove);
    }
};
```

So basically, we receive data, we insert it into a total array of data received. We stream it, and if we got at least one message, we remove it from the buffer `totalDataReceived`.

However, I am not sure it is the good way to go. Indeed, this code does not work when a compute a bad crc... (The message is not created, so we don't iterate over it). So each time, I am going to try to read the message with a bad crc...

How can I do this? I can not keep all the data in `totalDataReceived` because I can receive a lot of messages during the execution life time.

Should I implement my own streambuf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what you want to create is a class which acts like a std::istream. Of course you can choose to create your own class, but I prefer to implement std::streambuf for some reasons.

First, people using your class are accustomed to using it since it acts the same as std::istream if you inherit and implement std::streambuf and std::istream.

Second, you don't need to create extra method or don't need to override operators. They're already ready in std::istream's class level.

What you have to do to implement std::streambuf is to inherit it, override underflow() and setting get pointers using setg().

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
I am not creating a class that acts like a istream. I am creating a class that can be streamed through ` operator>>` . So I need to create the ` operator>> ` for Message class.

The issue is ` operator>>` can fail. If it fails, how can I handle such a thing properly :).

Comment: Hello, Antoine. Operator>> of std::istream may fail if there's not enough data in streambuf which you can check by invoking istream::fail(). You can check istream's failbit and continue after retrieving size and gotCrc from Message. Hope it helps.

Comment: Or, you can start using operator>> after fully receiving 246 bytes from socket if the size of message is fixed. In addition, there must not be endian mismatches.